# Iterate through object in ReactNative

Tags: arrays, mongodb, reactjs, react-native

I want to display all the objects within an array. But I can't make use of .map
Right now, if this is working and only displaying the first object:

```
<Text>{collaborateurs[0].collaborateur}</Text>
```

If I want to display the second object, then, this is working also

```
<Text>{collaborateurs[1].collaborateur}</Text>
```

But I need to iterate through the array because sometimes there are more than 2 entries.

I have tried this, but it returns "objects are not valid as a React Child

```
        <Text>
            <ul>
            {collaborateurs.map(function(name, index){
              return <li key={index}>{name}</li>;
            })}
          </ul>
        </Text>
```

Also here is the structure of the json file :

```
 "collaborateurs" : [ {
        "collaborateur" : "Mme Aurélie"
      }, {
        "collaborateur" : "Mme Charlotte"
      }, {
        "collaborateur" : "Mme Valérie"
      } ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Each object has the `collaborateur` property. When you iterate the array with map, you assign the object to the `name` variable, and then you try to render the object. In your "manual" examples, you access the `collaborateur` property directly - `collaborateurs[0].collaborateur`.

Destructure the property out of the object to get the string:

```
<Text>
    <ul>
    {collaborateurs.map(({ collaborateur }, index) => (
      return <li key={index}>{collaborateur}</li>;
    ))}
  </ul>
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects and you are assigning each element of the array to a variable `name`, so you are telling to React to use an object as child.
You need to use the attribute of said object that in your case is collaborateur.

```
 <Text>
     <ul>
         {collaborateurs.map((obj, index) => {
              return <li key={index}>{obj.collaborateur}</li>;
          })}
     </ul>
 </Text>
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation as iam a newbie it helps! Ok, now, it returns "View config not found for name li", an idea ?

Comment: As far as I recall React Native doesn't use the unordered list tags (`<ul>`,`<li>`). You need to build a list with the `ListView`, `View` and `Text` elements or use any library with a list implementation.